# SQL to Excel: Sum column with relative datetime condition

Tags: sql, excel, datetime, dynamic

I'm trying to make a shift-based overview of production output by drawing on data from a sql database into an excel sheet. This data is to be displayed on a screen for production status tracking.

SQL server: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) 11.0.3128.0 (x64)

My datatable looks like:

```
Product

| BatchID | EndedTime           | Prodline | Status |
| xxxx    | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |     x    |   x    |
| xxxx    | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |     x    |   x    |
| xxxx    | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |     x    |   x    |
| xxxx    | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |     x    |   x    |
| xxxx    | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |     x    |   x    |
```

Shifts are divided into day and night, 08:00-20:00 and 20:00-08:00 respectively. I want to have an overview counting the output for the current and previous shift like the following:

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|            | Previous shift | Current shift  |
| Production |---------------------------------|
|    line    |  OK  |   BAD   |  OK  |   BAD   |
|------------|------|---------|------|---------|
|      1     |  ##  |    #    |  ##  |    #    |
|      2     |  ##  |    #    |  ##  |    #    |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

I'm fairly inexperienced when it comes to programming but have managed to make a basic query for pulling data that works:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN Product.Status = OK AND Product.Prodline = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Line1_OK,
SUM(CASE WHEN Product.Status = BAD AND Product.Prodline = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Line1_BAD,
SUM(CASE WHEN Product.Status = OK AND Product.Prodline = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Line2_OK,
SUM(CASE WHEN Product.Status = BAD AND Product.Prodline = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Line2_BAD
FROM Product
WHERE Product.EndedTime IS NOT NULL
```

The (for me) tricky part is how to split the data for the two time intervals.
Based on the current time, I need to have one interval that is from the beginning of the current shift until NOW, and another that is the previous shift interval. I know how to do this in excel if I simply draw out a list and use COUNTIFS statements, but would like to have this in the sql query directly.

I reckon I would need to make 8 columns in my query and insert some time interval conditions in the WHEN statements. I just don't know how to implement these conditions. I have looked around threads here on the forum, but have not been able to get anything working.

For current:
if GETDATE() is earlier than 08:00:00 it should count from yesterday 20:00:00 until GETDATE().
if GETDATE() is between 08:00:00 and 19:59:59, it should count from 08:00:00 until GETDATE().
if GETDATE() is 20:00:00 or later it should count from 20:00:00 until GETDATE()

For previous:
Not sure how to make this in the most efficient way, but thinking it maybe could be the same method as for the current count with an extra 12 hours backwards included and then subtract the current count?

Comment: There are many types of databases so it would help to be a bit more specific about which one you're working with.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that. I did a SELECT @@Version query and it returned: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) 11.0.3128.0 (x64)

Comment: @TimWilliams , I've updated the question with the version info